# How can I get another report to be the last page in reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008, subreport

I have 2 reports that need to be printed together.

- The first report has a **header and footer that will repeat** (if necessary) on data overflow.
- The last page, which is a form to be sent back.

I basically need a way to print the last page without the repeated header/footers from the first report, and send in parameters to be used in the form.

Currently I have a rectangle that does a page break placed before my footer. Inside the rectangle I have my second report (subreport). I have the header and footer unchecked for print on last page.

I can get it down to 3 pages (upper-left, upper-right, and lower-right minus the header/footer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a property for the Header and Footers, called PrintOnLastPage

If you set that to False, it will not print the header and footer on the very last page of the report.

Comment: I've tried this, with little help. The problem is getting the second report to be it's own page. Currently what I have set up is a subreport within a rectangle that makes a page break; which is placed before the footer. I have both footer and header set not to print on last page. I've also removed the borders on the subreport. 

With this setup, I get the first page correctly, but 4 pages for the second report.

Comment: Why is the second report over 4 pages?  Is there whitespace above or below?

Comment: You may need to generate two separate reports in this case, in two separate ReportViewer controls.  I'm trying to imagine what is happening.  Maybe you could provide a screenshot of the report render?

Comment: The reason, is because for some reason the header/footer are still used -- even though the subreport on its own only makes 1 page.

Comment: It looks like it might be doing a page break at the wrong time?

Answer (score 0):

Having done this recently, here is how to do it. This processed is marred by SSRS severely lacking in features. First, you cannot insert a page break into a footer. Second, in order to print your last page, it cannot be in a subreport since subreports do not have headers or footers.

So, the solution I found in the end is to put the last page (in my case it was a terms and conditions sheet) in your main report's detail section, along with your header and footer (in their respective sections). Then add in the report that should come up in the first page as a subreport inside the detail section, above the last page, and separated from it with a page break, keeping in mind that any header or footer in this report will not show up (but shouldn't be too much of a problem to copy/paste the header and footer into your new "wrapper" report).

As for any extra white pages, check your margins. If your report is wider than the printer can support (including margins), a blank page will come out after every page. What I usually do is set the Top and Left margins and leave the Right and Bottom margins to 0, and adjust from there to get it centered.

Microsoft should really bite the bullet and do some updating to SSRS... Vanilla SSRS for years has been a sub-par solution compared to any of the many third party reporting packages out there, for no good reason. Just managing report files via the browser is a total pain, with no batch-based tools...